# MySQL Query Count and Join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I have the following query:

```
SELECT shipments.file_number, file_creation_date, city_name, container_sequence
FROM cities, countries, shipments
LEFT OUTER JOIN container_details ON shipments.file_number = container_details.file_number
WHERE
destination_ocean_port = city_code
AND cities.country_code = countries.country_code
AND cities.country_code = 'CN'
AND file_creation_date > '2015-1-1'
AND file_creation_date < '2016-1-1' 

ORDER BY shipments.file_number;
```

And it returns like this:

[image]

As you can see in some cases there are multiple container_sequences per file_number. How can I get it so it just returns one of each file_number while showing the count of how many container_sequences there are per each file_number?

I know it probably has something to do with joins and count() but I cannot figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: Try distinct(shipments.file_number), not sure if thats what you want

Comment: Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: So how does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the count() group by function and group by clause to achive the desired output. I also rewrote the joins to use inner joins with explicit join syntax.

```
SELECT shipments.file_number, file_creation_date, city_name, count(container_sequence) as number_of_containers
FROM cities 
INNER JOIN countries ON cities.country_code = countries.country_code
INNER JOIN shipments ON shipments.destination_ocean_port = cities.city_code
LEFT OUTER JOIN container_details ON shipments.file_number = container_details.file_number
WHERE 
    cities.country_code = 'CN'
AND file_creation_date > '2015-1-1'
AND file_creation_date < '2016-1-1' 
GROUP BY shipments.file_number, file_creation_date, city_name
ORDER BY shipments.file_number;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT shipments.file_number, file_creation_date, city_name, count(container_sequence) as total_container_sequence
FROM cities, countries, shipments
LEFT OUTER JOIN container_details ON shipments.file_number = container_details.file_number
WHERE
destination_ocean_port = city_code
AND cities.country_code = countries.country_code
AND cities.country_code = 'CN'
AND file_creation_date > '2015-1-1'
AND file_creation_date < '2016-1-1' 
GROUP BY shipments.file_number
ORDER BY shipments.file_number;
```

Comment: This will either work or not, depending on mysql configuration. But definitely not a good practice to have fields in the select list that are not in the group by list, nor are aggregated. Moreover, you are still using comma syntax for joins, which can have unexpected side effects.